# ElasticSearch -- incorrect value in one subfield of a multi field

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch, tokenize

ElasticSearch indexes my business documents with a multi-field for 'name', so that I can weight different degrees of name matching (exact match, one of many words, etc).  Here's a snippet from my mapping

```
"name" : {

                "type" : "multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "name":          {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index_analyzer"  : "AutoCompleteIndexAnalyzer",   "search_analyzer" : "AutoCompleteSearchAnalyzer"},
                    "exact_match":   {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index_analyzer"  : "ExactMatchNameIndexAnalyzer", "search_analyzer" : "ExactMatchNameSearchAnalyzer"},
                    "auto_name":     {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index_analyzer"  : "keyword",                     "search_analyzer" : "keyword"},
                 }
            },
```

Since it's a multi field, I only provide the value once -- ES just analyzes it multiple times.

So I am completely stumped on how the 'unbroken' subfield could get a completely incorrect value, while the 'name' subfield is right.  I couldn't understand why exact match wasn't working, so I wrote a script field to give me the 'exact_match' tokenization in search results:

```
"exact_match_tokenized_name": [
            "santininewyorkstyledeli"
        ],
"name": "Sal NY Pizza",
"name.auto_name": "Sal NY Pizza"
```

If anyone has any ideas on this, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it reproducible or it just happend to this one record?